# sass auto upload css file

Tags: ruby, synchronization, aptana

I'm developing a web project. 
It's my first time that I'm using sass, and I'm liking it. However I got a question related to synchronize the files. (I'm using Aptana studio as IDE)

When I make any change in any file and save it, AptanaStudio automatically synchronize with the  remote server and upload it... and thats great. 
But when I change my .scss file the .css file is updated but not synchronized with remote server. I have to manualy upload that file.

Is there any way I can make this process automatically? Any script? Any program?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're not using this uploading thing as a deployment process.

I don't know Aptana, but here is how it is supposed to work (in Rails >= 3.1 project):

- In development mode, assets (like css files) are generated by default.
- In production mode, assets are bundled and minimized into 1 file. To do this, you must run `rake assets:precompile` on your server. It is recommended to keep those generated files out of your (GIT/SVN) respository.

There is an [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) here. There is also a [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline) here, and also a [pro episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/341-asset-pipeline-in-production) on this topic, but that one will cost you $9.

Comment: Hi iain. Sorry, but I'm not working with rails. I tagged my post in a wrong way. already corrected. Thanks anyway